# Pass argument to fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a preference_headers.xml as follow. My activity is able to generate it without any problem. I'm wondering how to pass an argument (i.e. IP address string) from activity to fragment class. I am thinking to use findfragmentbyid() to access the specific fragment, however, I don't know how to add an ID at the header tag in preference_headers.xml.

Here is my sample code. Thanks

===== SetupActivity.java =======

```
public class SetupActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
    }
}
```

===== preference_headers.xml =======

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<header android:title="Network" />
<header 
    android:id="@+id/setting_wifi"
    android:fragment="com.example.setup.WIFIFragment" 
    android:title="@string/setting_wifi" >
</header>
</preference-headers>
```

===== WIFIFragment .java =======

```
public static class WIFIFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_wifi);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `SherlockPreferenceActivity` override this method

```
@Override
public void onHeaderClick(Header header, int position) {


    // Here's an example

    if(header.fragmentArguments == null)
    {
        header.fragmentArguments = new Bundle();
    }
    header.fragmentArguments.putString("IP", "Hi there! My IP is 127.0.0.1");

    super.onHeaderClick(header, position);

}
```

And you can obtain the argument in your Fragment

```
public static class WIFIFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_wifi);

        Bundle b = getArguments();
        if(b != null)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity() , b.getString("IP") , 1).show();
    }

}
```

I have tried this in Jelly bean not in Actionbar Sherlock library, but you can try it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findFragmentByTag()` to get the fragment. The tag name will need to be set when you're adding the fragment to the Activity.

Comment: How can add I the tag? I define the fragment at preference_headers.xml. Any sample code?

Comment: Personally I never used preference headers so I don't know. Does `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.setting_wifi)` not work?

Comment: No. It doesn't. I think R.id.setting_wifi is assoicated with header not fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I use 
    getPreferenceManager().findPreference(PREF_KEY).getExtras();

to get the extras bundle, and put whatever I want in it.